# Approximate a solution for $\frac{e^{-a}(v+u)(a^x+e^{a}x\Gamma(x,a))}{\Gamma(x+1)}-u\approx 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, exponential-function, roots, approximation-theory

Is it possible to approximate (or even find) a solution for the following equation:
$$\frac{e^{-a}(v+u)(a^x+e^{a}x\Gamma(x,a))}{\Gamma(x+1)}-u\approx0,$$

where $x\ge 0$ and integer, and the parameters $0<a<1$ and $u>0$, $v>0$.

It should be solved for $x$, can it be expressed in terms of the parameters?

Numerical methods show that such solution exists. For example, for $x=1$, $a=0.7$, $v=96.5543$ and $u=523$ the term value is $0.0246$.

Note: $x$ can be taken as a real number and then use the floor or ceiling functions to define the final expression.

Comment: Within you equation there is a $p$ used but you did not defined it.

Comment: Thanks @mrtaurho, fixed.

Comment: Can you give a numerical example? I'm not even sure which variable you're solving for. Also, what would be considered a good approximation?

Comment: Thanks @Maxim, I have re-edit the problem.

Comment: Using $v=96.52509765$ while keeping all of the other values the same gets you much closer to zero.  Also, all solutions for $x$ will only depend on $a$ and the ratio $r=v/u$.  To see that divide both sides of the equation by $u$.

Comment: Thank you for the observation @JimB, it seems right. Is there any further analysis that can be done here?

Comment: Not sure there's much more than noting that the ratio $u/v$ can be written in terms of $x$ and $a$:  $\frac{-a^x+e^a \Gamma (x+1)-e^a x \Gamma (x,a)}{a^x+e^a x \Gamma (x,a)}$.  Plotting $a$ vs $r$ for various integer values of $x$ might be informative.

Comment: If $a$ and $q = u/v$ are fixed and you're solving for $x$, it seems the lhs as a function of $x$ is monotonically increasing on $(-1, \infty)$ and always has a root there, finding which should be straightforward (the root may be negative). If you're allowing $x < -1$, the function has multiple zeroes on $(-\infty, -1)$, finding the zero closest to an integer will be more tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the remark @Maxim, but this equation comes from a physical situation where $x\ge 0$. I have added that to the question now. You mean finding the root numerically is straightforward? because I was looking for an arithmetic expression of some kind. Can you help?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant finding the root numerically. A closed form is unlikely to exist. If it can be proven that $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing (perhaps by going back to the original problem and considering where the incomplete gamma function came from?), then there is only one $n \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $f(n) \leq 0$ and $f(n + 1) > 0$, and the solution is either $x = n$ or $x = n + 1$. If $f(0) > 0$, the solution is $x = 0$.